# Set the JSLink property for all list forms in FeatureActivated

Tags: 2013, custom-form, feature-activation, jslink

Is it possible to update the [SPForm.JSLink property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spform.jslink.aspx) for the forms (Display, New, Edit) of an existing list in the when a feature is activated?

I have tried the code below, but it seems that the change is not being applied (i.e. the `JSLink` property is null on subsequent feature activations):

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    // ...
        someList.Forms.Cast<SPForm>().ToList().ForEach(form =>
        {
            form.JSLink = "~sitecollection/style library/myScript.js?v=" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
        });
    // ...
}
```

I have also tried calling `someList.Update()` after assigning the property, but still no effect.

Comment: Have you tried `someList.Update();` after the `foreach` is done?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the C# version of Anders answer as it was not as straightforward as I would have thought.

```
public static void SetFormJSLink(this SPList list, PAGETYPE formBaseView, string jsLinkUrl)
{
    var file = list.ParentWeb.GetFile(list.Forms[formBaseView].Url);
    file.CheckOut();

    using (var manager = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
    {
        var webPart = manager.WebParts.OfType<ListFormWebPart>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (webPart != null)
        {
            webPart.JSLink = jsLinkUrl ?? string.Empty;
            manager.SaveChanges(webPart);
        }
    }

    file.CheckIn("Added JSLink to the Form");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that for JSLink to work on the display/new/edit forms you need to set the JSLink on the webpart used in the forms, not directly on the form itself.

The following PowerShell code works for the new form on a blog post and should be easy to adopt to your needs in C#:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://myportal"
$file = $web.GetFile("Lists/Posts/NewPost.aspx")
$file.CheckOut()

$webPartManager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Lists/Posts/NewPost.aspx", [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
$webpart = $webPartManager.WebParts[0]
$webpart.JSLink = "YOUR JS URL HERE"

$webPartManager.SaveChanges($webpart)
$file.CheckIn("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `JSLink` property on the `SPView` rather than the form?

And call `Update()` on the view.

Note: I am also having problems with JSLink loading inconsistently!

Answer (score 0):

yes, setting property on view works!

```
var docwp = (XsltListViewWebPart)wpm.WebParts.Cast<System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart>().FirstOrDefault(wp => wp.Title.Equals("Documents"));
    docwp.View.JSLink = "~sitecollection/_layouts/15/styles/dscs/fancyDates.js";
    docwp.View.Update();
```