# How to include JavaScript in a list instance's form in Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, form

So I know you can use JSLink to include JavaScript files in list definitions in Schema.xml like so:

```
<Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" JSLink="~site/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" />
```

But how can I do this with a list instance that I'm provisioning that's based on the tasks list definition? Is there somewhere I can include JSLink in the instance's Elements.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would have your own custom list definition, you could deploy a custom form for your list instance, and set the `JSLink` element of the `Form`. You cannot set it "globally" for the list, only per form.

If your list instance is based on a built-in list instance (like Tasks in your case) you should set the `JSLink` property from code.
If you would like to deploy the list instance and set the `JSLink` property from a .wsp package, you should lookup the list form and set this property from a feature receiver. If you already created / deployed the list instance, the simplest method is to set the property via *PowerShell*. See the code samples for PowerShell and C# in [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77976/set-the-jslink-property-for-all-list-forms-in-featureactivated).

Comment: Perfect - adding JSLink in feature receiver code worked a treat. Thank you!